# FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(mAuth) not working as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently figuring out working with Firebase Auth in Android (MVP). My flow goes something like this:

```
Activity > Presenter > Interactor > AuthHelper
Activity < Presenter < Interactor < AuthHelper
```

The Auth Helper class is the sole class that directly interacts with the `FirebaseAuth` instance. My question is about how the AuthStateListener works in this scenario:

- Interactor has `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`
- Interactor initializes Auth Helper class, passing the `AuthStateListener`

  ```
  class MyInteractor implements FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {

      FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener;

      public MyInteractor(){
          MyHelper myHelper = new MyHelper(this);

          listener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
              @Override
              public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                  Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged called");
              }
          };
      }

      public void signOut(){
          myHelper.signOut();
      }
  }
  ```
- Helper passes the `FirebaseAuthInstance` to the listener

  ```
  class MyHelper {

      private static FirebaseAuth mAuth;

      public MyHelper(FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener listener){
          mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
          listener.onAuthStateChanged(mAuth);
      }

      public void signOut(){
          mAuth.signOut();
      }
  }
  ```
- `myHelper.signOut()` is called

Expected result:

`onAuthStateChanged()` in the interactor would trigger.

Received result:

`onAuthStateChanged()` is not triggered.

I instead tried a different approach where I passed the `mAuth` after calling `signOut()`:

```
public void signOut(){
    mAuth.signOut();
    listener.onAuthStateChanged(mAuth);
}
```

This triggers the `onAuthStateChanged`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can i see the presenter and activity?

Comment: Hi @UmarZaii I could add in a minimal code, but the activity and presenter doesn't communicate with the helper class - so I don't think it's necessary. Activity just calls the presenter to trigger the interactor signout.

Comment: where did you call the signOut() method? as mention that triggers onAuthStateChanged? Is it inside activity?

Comment: It gets called in the Helper class (see `MyHelper` class), from that call, I was expecting that the `onAuthStateChanged()` in the interactor gets triggered.

Comment: I mean where did you call the method signOut() which is public void signOut(). Not mAuth.signOut(). Where did you call the method?

Comment: In the Interactor -- I'll add that in if it helps in visualizing it.

Comment: Thank you please do so. I'm trying to figure it out :)

Comment: The posted `MyInteractor` doesn't compile for me.  Must be abstract or implement `onAuthStateChanged()`.  ???

Comment: Hi @BobSnyder Thanks for looking into this. I've managed to get the behavior I was aiming for (I've added the answer below). Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a few more researching, I realized that

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(listener)
```

is what I really needed to use for my flow instead of `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(mAuth)`. I misunderstood the way it worked and it ended up biting me.

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44860537/4625829) as the main saver.